# Converting double to int array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to XOR each letter from my TextBox with each value from my array. 
The problem is, that when I convert `double` to `int` array, my `int` array `result` stores only one value.

If I run my code I get first letter XORed, but if I input more then one, I get message :

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

I have tried myself to create an int array like: `int[] result = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};` and I didn't have any problems with XORing up to 7 letters..

```
        private void iTalk_Button_12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ambiance_RichTextBox1.Text = XorText(ambiance_RichTextBox1.Text);
        }
        private string XorText(string text)
        {

            string newText = "";
            double r = 3.9;
            double[] first_value = new double[text.Length];
            double[] to_int_array = new double[text.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            {
                double get_first = r * i * (1 - i);
                int index = (int)(i * text.Length);
                first_value[index] = get_first;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            {

                int xnbb = 0;
                if (first_value[i] > Math.Exp(Math.Log(2) * (-i)))
                {
                    double get_first = first_value[i] - Math.Exp(Math.Log(2) * (-i));
                    xnbb = 1;
                }

                double array_of_values = xnbb + 1 * Math.Round(Math.Exp(Math.Log(2) * (24 - i)));

                int index = (int)(i * text.Length);
                to_int_array[index] = array_of_values;
                int[] result = new int[] { Convert.ToInt32(to_int_array[i]) };


                int charValue = Convert.ToInt32(text[i]);
                charValue ^= result[i]%320;
                newText += char.ConvertFromUtf32(charValue);
            }
            return newText;  
        }
```

Comment: Throw away this code and start over with a flowchart.  I don't believe there's a single line of code here that makes sense.  Oh alright, maybe `return newText;` can stay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        double[] first_value = new double[text.Length];
        ... 
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            double get_first = r * i * (1 - i);
            int index = (int)(i * text.Length);
            first_value[index] = get_first;
        }
```

When the text length is 2, first_value index may run from 0..1. i will loop from 0 to 1. the calculated index becomes 1 x 2 = 2, and that is beyond the index range.

Answer (score 1):

When passing a string with 2 characters to `XorText`, the System.IndexOutOfRangeException is thrown in this Line:

```
 first_value[index] = get_first;
```

because the index is `2` when the loop body is executed the second time:

```
 int index = (int)(i * text.Length);
```

You really should consider learning how to use a debugger. It will make programming easier.